# A degree of an embedding and a self-intersection of a hyperplane section

Tags: algebraic-geometry, surfaces, projective-geometry

Let $X$ be a surface inside $\mathbb{P}^3$ of degree $d$, that is given as $f=0$ where $f(x, y, z, w)$ is a homogenous polynomial of degree $d$. Let $\tilde{H}$ be a class of a hyperplane section in $\mathbb{P}^3$ and let $H$ be its restriction to $X$. I want to prove that $H^2=d$. It contradicts my intuition because of the following reason: it seems that $H=\tilde{H} \cap X$ should be a curve of degree $d$ on $X$ and, therefore, by Bezout's theorem the intersection of two general divisors linearly equivalent to $H$ should consist of $d^2$ points meaning that $H^2=d^2$ instead of $H^2=d$.

What is wrong with my intuition?

Comment: Recall that Bézout, as it is usually stated, is for curves in $\mathbb{P}^2$. But $X$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{P}^2$ in general, so it is not clear how compute $H^2$.

Comment: Nevertheless, one might expect the following: if we have three hypersurfaces $S_1, S_2, S_3$ in $\mathbb{P}^3$ of degrees $d_1, d_2, d_3$, then $S_1 \cap S_2 \cap S_3$ should consist on $d_1d_2d_3$ points. (Under some extra assumptions, e.g. "general" hypersurfaces.) Then $H^2 = \overline{H} \cap \overline{H} \cap X$ should consist of $1 \cdot 1 \cdot d=d$ points. (This is not directly true, but it gives the correct intuition here.)

Comment: @NicolásVilches that makes sense but it is really a surprising fact. Imagine that Pic(X) is small, for example, Z. Then two curves of degree d should be linearly equivalent. In particular, it implies that two general curve of degree d intersect in d points! (assuming X is of degree d in P^3). It's really surprising.

Comment: It is a bit surprising! Have you thought about the first nontrivial case, i.e. $d=2$? I'll write some ideas about it as an answer.

Comment: @NicolásVilches Yes, I was trying to write down something for a quadric surface but it was hard to convert my writings into geometric pictures and so I decided to ask it here. Would be happy to accept your thoughts as an answer!

Comment: Dear iou, I notice that you've made one vote on an answer through your entire MSE career - in particular, you didn't vote on the answer below. Is there a reason you don't vote on answers, especially answers to your own questions? (NB: I am not the answerer, but I do think they did a good job and I voted on the answer myself.)

Comment: @KReiser There is no a good reason, it's just my bad attitude. I agree that I should have voted many times; especially that I have seen a lot of great answers even among answers to my questions. I will be more careful from that moment, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us work "by hand" the first nontrivial example, namely $d=2$. We fix
$$ X= V(x_0x_3-x_1x_2) \subset \mathbb{P}^3. $$
As it is well known, we can identify $X$ with $\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$, using the isomorphism
$$ \Phi\colon \mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1 \to X, \qquad [y_0, y_1], [z_0, z_1] \mapsto [y_0z_0, y_0z_1, y_1z_0, y_1z_1]. $$
Now, consider some hyperplane $\overline{H}=V(F)$, where $F=a_0x_0+a_1x_1+a_2x_2+a_3x_3$. The intersection $\overline{H} \cap X$ is then computed as
$$ \overline{H} \cap X = V(\Phi^\ast F)=V(a_0y_0z_0+a_1y_0z_1+a_2y_1z_0+a_3y_1z_1). $$
This is, $H \subset \mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$ (identifying $H$ with its preimage under $\Phi$) is a curve of bidegree $(1,1)$ inside $\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$.

Now, it is not so difficult to convnince ourselves that if $H, H'$ are "sufficiently nice" $(1,1)$ curves, then $H \cdot H'=2$. For instance, if $H=V(x_0y_0)$ and $H'=V(x_1y_1)$, then $H \cdot H'=2$ by counting the intersections.